# Not all the records are being updated in DynamoDB

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

We are updating records in DynamoDB through DynamoDB Java SDK. Sometimes there are around 100 rows that need to be updated. Only half of the rows are being updated, and the remaining doesn't get updated.

This is happening only with one DynamoDB table. The same works fine with the other table. I want to know if is there any configuration at the table side that I am missed to update or set?

Comment: Add more  details like configuration table structure to find out the problem

Comment: Can you tell me if you want to know any specific configuration?